# Weird characters sharing in facebook from wordpress blog

Tags: facebook, wordpress, encoding, character-encoding, sharing

I have a wordpress blog and every time I share a page e.g. http://atthepigsty.chunterings.com/2012/07/18/to-wait-or-to-trust/ on facebook I get weird characters in the text.

I already have the utf-8 meta tag in place which is the normal advice to solve this sort of thing.

Does anyone know how fix this?

Ta
C

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Open Graph meta tags on your page, so you're at the mercy of what Facebook scrapes from your site. For some reason, FB is translating your commas into those goofy characters.

See the results of your web page in the Facebook debugger: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fatthepigsty.chunterings.com%2F2012%2F07%2F18%2Fto-wait-or-to-trust%2F

The easiest way to fix this is by adding a plugin to add these open graph tags for you. I personally like [Yoast's Wordpress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/). The official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) also has promise. I'm using it for some of its other features, but I've added code in my theme's `functions.php` to remove its Open Graph tags since I like what WP SEO outputs better.

There are lots of other plugins out there that add these tags. You need to be careful: I've ended up with too many OG tags on several occasions as plugin feature creep occurs. Run your site through the debugger after every upgrade, or you won't know what is going on.